# X plus minus 10 percent.

Tags: percentages

I have $x = 100$. I need to get a range that is plus/minus $10\%$ of $100$.

That means in my case $x=100$:

- $10\%$ of $100$ = $10$
- $100 - 10 = 90$
- $100 + 10 = 110$

That means my range of $100 \pm 10\%$ is: $90 - 110$

Correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct............

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct. Do you want a curious fact? You have $100$, you add $10\%$ and you have $110$. Then you take away $10\%$ (that now is worth $11$) and you end up with $99\%$. After adding and afterwards deducting the same $10\%$, you lose $1\%$.

Bad luck? Let's try reversing the process. Start again with $100$ but this time start subtracting $10\%$, so you have $90$. Now add $10\%$ of that and you have... $99$ again!

Comment: Don't confuse the op with the "curious fact."  What you describe shouldn't be surprising anyways since the 10%'s are not 10% of the same quantity.  $1.1\cdot 0.9\neq 1$.

Comment: I don't think this is confusing. Maybe it is "warning". Some people might be seriously surprised (if not _disappointed_) if they find themselves with assets not fully recovering their value after after reading on the newspapers one day -10% and the day after +10%...

Comment: Does this phenomenom have a name?

Comment: @Worthy7 Not one that I'm aware of